# MySQL : One to One Relationship Tables Merging

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to simplify an application's database. In that database I have two tables let's say `Patient` and `MedicalRecord`. I know that two tables are said to be in One-to-One relationship iff that any given row from `Table-A` can have `at most` one row ine `Table-B`(It means there can be zero matchings).

But in my case, it is not `at most`, it is `exactly`. i.e., Every row in `Patient` should have `exactly` one row in `MedicalRecord`(no patient exist without a medical record).

`Patient` table has all personal details of the patient with his id as `PK`.
`MedicalRecord` talbe has details like his blood-group, haemoglobin, bp etc with his id as both `PK` and `FK` to the `Patient`.

My Question is, can I merge those two tables and create one table like,

`PatientDetails` : personal_details and blood-group, haemoglobin, bp etc

Comment: If what you describe is correct, then technically, both versions are valid representations of your relation, you are allowed to merge them. You can even do it with 1:0, since you can simply leave every value null. You will split 1:1-realtions up into seperate tables more for logical reasons. But I would check your original hypothesis. While a blood group will usually not change, I would assume that blood pressure, haemoglobin and such will depend on time, so you might have several values for different times (e.g if the same patient visits a second time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bp" = "Blood pressure"?  Then you must *not* combine the tables.  Instead, it is 1:many -- each patient can have many sets of readings.  It is very important to record and plot trends in the readings.

Put only truly constant values in the `Patient` -- name, birthdate (*not* age; compute that), sex, race (some races are more prone to certain diseases than others), not height/weight.  Etc.

Sure, a patient may have a name change (marriage, legal action, etc), but that is an exception that does not affect the schema design, except to force you to use `patient_id`, not `patient_name` as a unique key.

Every patient must have a `MedicalRecord`?  That is "business logic"; test it in the application; do not depend (in this case) on anything in the Database.

Both tables would have `patient_id`.  `Patients` would have it as the `PRIMARY KEY`; `MedicalRecord would have`INDEXed`.  That's all it takes to have 1:many.

In situations where the tables are really 1:1 (optionally 1:0/1), I do recommend merging the table.  (There are exceptions.)

Comment: can you elaborate this => "bp" = "Blood pressure"? Then you must not combine the tables.

Comment: Blood pressure does change, so it should _not_ be part of the single row for each patient.

Answer (score 1):

If two tables have the same set of subrow values for a shared set of columns that is a superkey in both (SQL PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE) then you can replace the two tables by their natural join. ("Natural join" is probably what you mean by "merge" but that is not a defined technical term.) Each original table will equal the projection of the join on that original's columns.

(1:1 means total on both sides, it does not mean 1:0-or-1, although most writing about cardinalities is sloppy & unclear.)